# this.flashMessage.show is not a function

Tags: angular

I am using angular2-flash-messages in my application for notification. On successful sign up, I have to show that user is registered. But I am facing an error which says, "

> this.flashMessage.show is not a function

"

**signup.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  name: String;
  username: String;
  email: String;
  password;

  constructor(
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onRegisterSubmit() {
    const user = {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    };

    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        this.flashMessage.show('You are registered and can login.');
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay! So I tried the solutions that have been posted but none of them worked completely. I looked at documentation and I realised that i forgot to add `<flash-messages></flash-messages>` in the template file **(app.component.html)**. That's why it is unable to render and gives the error that it's not a function because that function is unable to return any value.

Answer (score 2):

Check using this

```
  this._flashMessagesService.show('We are in about component!', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 1000 });
```

[`More on usage`](https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages#usage)

[**Stackblitz working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test)

Comment: @faceturn i get that but i think  he has just added the usage data from the git page and i just happen to make a workable example , makes it clearer on how i got the answer i didnot invent the same

Comment: A dv for the same great , can you just reveal who has given the dv

Answer (score 1):

Make a local declaration of flashMessage in onSubmit() or method where you want to use this.

Like this:

```
var flashMessage = this.flashMessage;
```

Then add 
`<flash-messages></flash-messages>` in the template file (app.component.html).

It worked for me.
Hope it helps.